# Freebsd 12 i386 MongoDB package doesn't exist

Tags: freebsd, x86, database, mongodb

Installed Freebsd 12.1 i386, when I am using `pkg search mongodb` I get "mongodb tools" and "mongodb C driver" and some other "mongodb" related packages but there is no mongodb database. Does this mean mongodb is not supported on X86? Or I am doing something wrong?
That means I can't install mongodb from ports too, or If I can, there will be something wrong with database, right?

**Update**
I found [MongoDB supported-platforms](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#supported-platforms): "Changed in version 3.4: MongoDB no longer supports 32-bit x86 platforms" but there is no freebsd there.

By the way, I am new to freebsd and just started learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Does this mean mongodb is not supported on X86?"*

A: Yes. Mongodb was marked 64 bit only [Feb 2016](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/commit/3c9cd92c76f5b00efe5a98dfd2c1de93867cb8a4).

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try that and hope everything works fine. It's taking time.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: I tried to install from ports and it says: mongodb42 is only for aarch64 amd 64. But thanks again.